# Facing issue when i upgrade magento 2.4.4 and php8.1 and mysql 8 after composer upgrade

Tags: magento2.4.4

facing error when i upgrade magento 2.4.4 with php 8.1, mysql 8.0 and using composer upgrade getting error below

> Fatal error: During inheritance of Countable: Uncaught Exception:
> Deprecated Functionality: Return type of
> Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository::count() should either be
> compatible with Countable::count(): int, or the
> #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in
> vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ArrayRepository.php
> on line 277 in n vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61

---

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem may be that you've upgraded to PHP 8.1 before you've upgraded your composer packages. Have a read of this github issue, seems others had the same issue:

- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/35306

From this thread, it seems like the accepted approach is:

- **STAY IN PHP 7.4**
- `composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin ~2.0 --no-update`
- `composer update`
- `rm -rf var/cache/* ; rm -rf var/page_cache/* ; rm -rf generated/code/*;` - `bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `composer require-commerce magento/product-community-edition 2.4.4 --no-update`
- `composer update`
- **CHANGE TO PHP 8.1**
- `rm -rf var/cache/* ; rm -rf var/page_cache/* ; rm -rf generated/code/*;`
- `bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Of course, if you're a developer and owner of your codebase - I'd advise you first check for any overwritten files that may need updating as part of the upgrade with https://github.com/AmpersandHQ/ampersand-magento2-upgrade-patch-helper

Comment: It works, just a comment: the second 'composer update' needs to run with php8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Liam Toohey, But not worked. I found another solution. That is worked

As of PHP 8.1, you have to fix the return type of the functions count(). We need to modify 2 files.

Change public function count() to public function count(): int

Goto => \vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository.php (line 277)

```
public function count(): int
    {
    if (null === $this->packages) {
        $this->initialize();
    }
    return count($this->packages);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Temporary solution:

```
vendor\composer\composer\src\Composer\Repository\ArrayRepository.php 
or 
vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Repository/CompositeRepository.php

// public function count()
   public function count(): int
```